# Is there any emulator for Amazon fire stick?

Tags: android-studio, amazon-fire-tv

1. If i develop an app for amazon fire stick but I don't have a Fire stick so how can I check my app?
2. Is there any emulator for Amazon fire stick ?

Answer (score 3):

When you use regular `Android Emulator` it's not acting as real **firestick** device. You will get some new issues with your app when running on `Fire OS`. So better to use real device and connect that through `adb`.

Answer (score 1):

See [this post](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/fire-app-builder/use-an-android-tv-emulator.html) on the Amazon Developer docs for some pointers on how to get it working in the emulator. There are some limitations, and from experience I'd probably recommend getting one to work with if you're going to be doing much work with it

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can create an Android TV emulator and run your app inside it. Follow these steps here: https://developer.amazon.com/docs/fire-app-builder/use-an-android-tv-emulator.html